# Why is my Mac persistently scanning multicast address?

Tags: networking, mac, multicast

I have a Linux machine with `Psad` installed. 
When I observe the log reports generated (admittedly I have Psad configured to be particularly sensitive), it lists a large number of scans originating from my `Apple MacBook-air (OS X 10.11.6)`, directed towards the multicast address `224.0.0.1`.

This is not the only Apple device on my local network, however it is unique in it's network activity in this regard, and I am curious why.

Below is a `nmap` scan list of services from the offending Mac, in case it provides any relevant details.

```
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
548/tcp   open  afp
625/tcp   open  apple-xsrvr-admin
49152/tcp open  unknown
```

In short: **Why would my MacBook-Air be repeatedly scanning the multicast address 224.0.0.1, and therefor all addresses on the local subnet?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software) , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)

Comment: The _actually_ relevant details would be what kind of packets you saw that were considered "scans". Were they UDP packets? Which port were they sent to? What data did they contain? (Does your firewall just blindly call _anything_ it doesn't recognize a "scan"?)